# Why is $ChildScope.$parent.$parent.$root.$root...is spiral?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular/js and trying to build an app using Sails.

When I made an index.html, whose controller I used to print the $scope value on the console, I saw the attached screenshot.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller='angHomeController'>
```

And here is my controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('angHomeController', function($scope, $location) {
  console.log($scope);
});
```

And here's what I see on the console.[image]

Out of many questions that popped up on my mind, few are below.

Before going into developing/creating/using anymore template-controller variables/closures/callbacks, I wanted to understand few things about this.

Q. #1. The depth of the tree in this is - $ChildScope.$parent.$parent (which is inherited from Scope). I see $ChildScope.$parent.$parent.$$listeners as locationChangeStart, locationChangeSuccess and routeChangeSuccess arrays with their *proto*(s). Can I think this $parent.$parent is created by the Sails MVC Framework using the $routeProvider API of angular?

Q. #2. I would assume the top most in the tree, $ChildScope, is created by the ng-controller upon the $rootScope.$new. But, I'm still intrigued why the tree is $ChildScope.$parent.$parent, instead of $ChildScope.$parent? Am I missing something? The $ChildScope.$parent doesn't have watchers or listeners. The $ChildScope, of course, doesn't have any listeners as I haven't created any events.

Q. #3. I also observe that $ChildScope.$parent doesn't have $root, but $ChildScope.$parent.$parent.$root is existing and it seems to be a reference to $ChildScope.$parent.$parent. Also, the $ChildScope.$parent.$parent.$root.$root...is spiral and doesn't end. The last $parent's reference is $root, which has a $root and so on. Why doesn't this root chain exist and where does it take its reference from?

Comment: the top most scope is `$rootScope`.

Comment: I get that the top most scope is $rootScope. But, the only thing I'm trying to understand is the scope inheritance in Sails with a simple ng-controller and my understandings on it.

Answer (score 0):

Angular scopes 'mimic' DOM structure of an application.

Scopes are created for the Angular App, each Angular controller and some directives (if you do specify that the directive should create or reuse a scope).

Playing with $scope.$parent.$parent is not recommended as it is very fragile. If you change your angular controller or any directive around the DOM tree, your scope hierarchy will be affected.

I'd recommend reading [What are scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) on angular website.

Comment: I understand Angular scopes mimic DOM structures and scopes and yes, I've read the URL before starting to write an angularJs program. And yes, as I too stated in my Q #2, Angular controller created a ChildScope. But, that should have created a tree of $ChildScope.$parent but not $ChildScope.$parent.$parent. Moreover, I'm not playing with any parent objects in the tree. All I'm trying to know is - how the $root goes spiral below the last $parent.